# Ffmpeg sync error, first image showing really fast

Tags: ffmpeg, video-editing, video-conversion

I want to converting my images with mp3 to videos... but first slide is showing up really fast.

I want to each slide duration 5-7 seconds or so

RAW material

- [MP3 Files](http://www.mediafire.com/?btweyh05pcrb8bl)
- [My list Images](http://www.mediafire.com/?6ktfd0cjm7a9moc)
- [FFmpeg git-7e5c5fa 32-bit Static (Latest) (2013-01-10)](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/win32/static/ffmpeg-20130110-git-7e5c5fa-win32-static.7z)

Here my command

```
ffmpeg  -r 1/7 -i "manga%01d.png" -i "sound1.mp3" -c:a aac -strict experimental -b:a 128k -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -shortest -r 27 -y "product000.mp4"
```

LOG:

```
ffmpeg version N-48731-g7e5c5fa Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jan 10 2013 19:47:49 with gcc 4.7.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib --enable-filter=frei0r
  libavutil      52. 13.100 / 52. 13.100
  libavcodec     54. 86.100 / 54. 86.100
  libavformat    54. 59.107 / 54. 59.107
  libavdevice    54.  3.102 / 54.  3.102
  libavfilter     3. 32.100 /  3. 32.100
  libswscale      2.  1.103 /  2.  1.103
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
  libpostproc    52.  2.100 / 52.  2.100
Input #0, image2, from 'manga%01d.png':
  Duration: 00:00:00.32, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgba, 640x360 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
[mp3 @ 02845880] max_analyze_duration 5000000 reached at 5015510
[mp3 @ 02845880] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #1, mp3, from 'sound1.mp3':
  Metadata:
    TSS             : Logic Pro 8.0.2
    genre           : Electronic
    TCM             : Kevin MacLeod
    album           : Disco and Lounge
    TKE             : C
    TBP             : 95
    title           : One Sly Move
    artist          : Kevin MacLeod
    date            : 2008-10-23 01:31
  Duration: 00:02:44.69, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 320 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 320 kb/s
    Stream #1:1: Video: mjpeg, yuvj444p, 400x400, 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
    Metadata:
      title           : ÿØÿà
      comment         : Other
[libx264 @ 024c6e00] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 024c6e00] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 FastShuffle SSE4.2
[libx264 @ 024c6e00] profile High, level 3.0
[libx264 @ 024c6e00] 264 - core 129 r2230 1cffe9f - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2012 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'product000.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf54.59.107
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 640x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 13824 tbn, 27 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (png -> libx264)
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:1 (mp3 -> aac)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=  190 fps=0.0 q=29.0 size=      43kB time=00:00:05.11 bitrate=  68.8kbits/s dup=188 drop=0    
frame=  379 fps=315 q=29.0 size=     117kB time=00:00:12.11 bitrate=  79.4kbits/s dup=376 drop=0    
frame=  568 fps=271 q=29.0 size=     250kB time=00:00:19.11 bitrate= 107.1kbits/s dup=564 drop=0    
frame=  757 fps=241 q=29.0 size=     387kB time=00:00:26.11 bitrate= 121.4kbits/s dup=752 drop=0    
frame=  946 fps=218 q=29.0 size=     514kB time=00:00:33.11 bitrate= 127.2kbits/s dup=940 drop=0    
frame= 1135 fps=216 q=29.0 size=     649kB time=00:00:40.11 bitrate= 132.5kbits/s dup=1128 drop=0
```

Comment: Might be worth looking at this: [Why is the first image changing so quickly when creating video from images via FFmpeg?](http://superuser.com/questions/434232/why-is-the-first-image-changing-so-quickly-when-creating-video-from-images-via-f)

Comment: @slhck

already tried that.... but still no works... :), maybe are you have alternative ( Its been a month since I have using ffmpeg, but still no solid solution )

Comment: You could ask your question on the `ffmpeg-user` mailing list as well if you like: http://ffmpeg.org/mailman/listinfo/ffmpeg-user — If you include samples and everything and others reproduce the issue, this might be considered a bug.

Comment: @slhck

thanks, I will go there, and see what I got...

Comment: see also http://superuser.com/a/552718/39364